# Trying to call a list of first and last names but returns a mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I created a form that recalls information from a sheet i.e. first and last names. In the name combobox,  when typing the name out on the form, if you type a name that isn't located on the list, a mismatch occurs. How do I remedy this? If I remove the 0 value the function no longer matches correctly.

*** Call previous fields ***

```
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()

If Me.ComboBox4.Text <> "" Then

 Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Dim i As String

  i = Application.Match(Me.ComboBox4.Value, sh.Range("A:A"), 0)


    Me.TextBox2.Value = sh.Range("B" & i).Value

    If sh.Range("H" & i).Value = "Introduced" Then Me.OptionButton1.Value = True
    If sh.Range("H" & i).Value = "Not Introduced" Then Me.OptionButton2.Value = True


    Me.ComboBox1.Value = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
    Me.ComboBox2.Value = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
    Me.ComboBox3.Value = sh.Range("M" & i).Value

    Me.TextBox11.Value = sh.Range("J" & i).Value
     Me.TextBox10.Value = sh.Range("K" & i).Value
       Me.TextBox9.Value = sh.Range("L" & i).Value
     Me.TextBox12.Value = sh.Range("I" & i).Value
  Me.TextBox5.Value = sh.Range("G" & i).Value
    Me.TextBox7.Value = sh.Range("N" & i).Value
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: If the name is not found `i` will return a error when trying to `Match` the name in range. You need to code for the chance of error

Comment: `i` should be a `Variant`, and then use `IsError` to test whether it's an error.

Comment: Or, why not just use `Find`? Easier to handle errors (`If Not i Is nothing Then`)

Comment: .... though don't use `i` as the variable name here. i.e. something different than `i As Variant`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using functions native to VBA makes things a little easier. You can use `Range.Find` instead of the worksheet function `Match` for your code.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
Dim xName As Range

Set xName = sh.Range("A:A").Find Me.ComboBox4.Value

If xName Is Nothing Then

    'End sub if not found
    MsgBox "Name Not Found - Existing Sub"

Else

    'To access the row use xName.Row
    Me.TextBox2.Value = sh.Range("B" & xName.Row).Value

    '.... rest of code

End If
```

Comment: So now when activate my button and type in the combobox, I get runtime error 91

Comment: @MoAbbasi Whenever you get an error, it always helps to share what line gave the error. I think you have to remove the parenthesis (updated in my code already)